# Set div scrollTop property after component render

Tags: reactjs

I have functional component `<Container id="container ...` which is rendered on button (`<a href="#container" ...`) click and i need to set Container `div.scrollTop` property.

What i want to achieve

1. User clicks the button
2. Container component is rendered below
3. User browser scrolls to end of newly created component

I've completed first two steps but i am unable to set scrollTop property of the div Container. I've tried to assign property in useEffect hook but every time it's equal 0

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative maybe you can make it simple, with state, show component if the state is true, and then you can animate it with `element.scrollTo` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo